# erasing entry from boost vector

Tags: c++, vector, boost, erase

First off, I'm relatively new to boost.
I have a vector of type: `boost::container::vector<std::string> plates`
and i iterate through it with
 `for ( unsigned int k = 0; k < plates.size(); k++ )`, so far so good. 
Now, I need to erase elements from within the loop and I attempted the following:
`plates.erase(plates.begin()+k);` but that gives me the below output and terminates my application:

```
include/boost/container/vector.hpp:1595: boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::reference boost::container::vector<T,
, Options>::size_type) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Allocator = boost::container::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Options = void; boost
:basic_string<char>&; boost::container::vector<T, Allocator, Options>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion `this->m_holder.m_size > n' failed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?
My loop looks something like this where`foo()` returns a pointer or NULL:

```
for ( unsigned int k = 0; k < plates.size(); k++ ) {
        if (foo(&lpmap, plates[k]) != NULL){
                std::cout << "DEBUG: erase" << std::endl;
                plates.erase(plates.begin()+k);
        } else {
            std::cout << "print " << plates[k] << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
for ( unsigned int k = 0; k < plates.size();) {
        if (foo(&lpmap, plates[k]) != NULL){
                std::cout << "DEBUG: erase" << std::endl;
                plates.erase(plates.begin()+k);
        } else {
            std::cout << "print " << plates[k] << std::endl;
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't know if this is the main cause, but when you `erase` and the do `k++`, you have missed one position.

Comment: [Erase-remove_idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: @BoPersson See **EDIT1** above, that should work then, right?

Answer (score 1):

There is an assertion in boost that checks if you try to access an index out of range. so if you used `plates[k]` with k more than actual size, you get an assertion.

You can see the check right in the boost code: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/container/vector.hpp.